# Signal processing and algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, signal-processing, sampling

Signal processing is a pretty huge branch of what I would (maybe wrongly) call electrical engineering. I have heard here and there whispers of interesting connections between signal processing - in particular sampling theory - and algebraic geometry.

I am not interested in "local" applications to solve specific problems. Instead, I'm looking for something like a general approach to signal processing and sampling theory which intrinsically uses notions of algebraic geometry. Kind of like the approach to number theory via algebraic geometry.

I am very interested to read how these two fields relate to each other and would be grateful for references.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm all for nonsensical humor, but I don't understand what a fish head on a raw chicken smoking a cigarette has to do with an argument being invalid (commenting on your avatar).

Comment: Absolutely nothing! Such is the power of the internet!